# Can a polarizer let scattered laser light pass in order to filter ambient light?

Tags: optics, scattering, laser, polarization

I am currently working on a project in which I need to detect the image of a line laser (I haven't choosen the laser yet, most likely a low-cost one) with a camera (most likely basic CMOS camera).
By line laser, I am refering to laser beam spread in one of its axis.

Ambient light can deeply impact line detection, and although there exists some software solutions, I would like to try for some opticals solutions.

By reading some topics here and there, I learned that laser light can be polarized without use of a polarizer, depending on the manufacturing process and the materials involved.

I've been thinking of using a polarizer (choosen accordingly to the laser polarization) in front of the camera lens, to filter ambient light (most likely sunlight) as I know that sunlight is weakly (if not, non-) polarized.

From the little knowledge I have in wave optics (roughly 2nd-3rd year of undergraduate), I think that the laser light seen by the camera is the result of the scattering (and not reflection) of the laser beam on the surface (in case it is non reflective) it is casted upon.

The question would then be : **Is the laser light scattered by the surface polarized ? And if so, is it isotropic** (I think that's the word used to describe that the light is polarized with the same polarization independently from the direction) **?**

I'm not sure that the two previous questions, which are in fact the conditions for filtering ambient light and letting laser light through, are sufficient for my idea to work.

I might be completely wrong, so please, do not hesitate to correct me if necessary. 
Also please keep in mind that it's a **line laser** and not a dot laser.

Comment: Hi, it looks like a great project. But to be able to help, we need more specific information.  By "line laser," do you mean the beam has been spread in one axis, or is it scanning a "point beam" across one axis?   Your use of the words "diffusion" and "reflection" are incorrect, so it's hard to figure out what you are doing.  Posting a diagram of the experiment setup would be a huge help.

Comment: In the meantime, try to get a "line filter" bandpass filter which rejects all wavelengths except the laser wavelength.  That will do a far better job of removing ambient light.

Comment: Hi @Carl, thank you for your comment ! Indeed my use of the word "diffusion" is incorrect, I've fallen in a translation trap, from french to english. I think the correct word is "scattering".
I don't understand how my use of the word "reflection" is incorrect though. I edited the post and the title.

Thanks again for your feedback. Do you think it might be relevant to use a polarizer in addition to a wavelength filter ? 
I'll work on a diagram !

Comment: Yes, that is clearer.  I think in English we would refer to "specular reflection" for what you get from, say, a mirror surface.  Diffuse or scattered reflections are, as you say, what a rough surface produces.  You might get some useful information by looking up "BRDF" , aka "bidirectional reflectance distribution function" too!

Comment: Okay thanks again for your help ! I'll definitely give it a look, it seems really interesting !

Comment: Do you really have a laser experiment in a sunlit room? Most people work in a darken or completely dark room.

Comment: @trula  Not necessarily.   Consider, for example, the huge field of  LIDAR mapping in the "great outdoors" .  There are many other cases where a laser is desirable, due to narrow linewidth, coherence,etc. for monitoring something in the open environment.